How to use digital mics such as Neumann KM 184 D to avoid going through an A to D converter and input directly to the daw
I want to use several digital mics (such as Neumann KM 184 D) directly into the DAW. The problem is that I have not found a unit allowing me to connect the mics and then inputting all these mics into the PC via one USB cable, while keeping all mics separate (to assign them individually on a track of the DAW).
Is this feasible?

Seems like one big interface that has a bunch of mic pres would be a lot easier than buying several one-channel interfaces built into microphones (cause that’s what digital mics are). Note that you can only avoid going through a DA converter by using analog tape instead of a DAW. Digital mics still have analog to digital converters built into them.

The KM 184 D seems to output AES3 signal. https://www.neumann.com/en-us/products/historical/kk-184--km-d/ . So any digital interface with AES 3 inputs should be able to deal with them.
